# Mat-button style not applying in Mat-menu

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular 11 project with a custom dropdown component which uses mat-menu for showing dropdown items.

I am passing a mat-button inside this dropdown component (along with the other menu items) that isn't working properly. When I add `color="accent"` mat-button's `background-color` doesn't change. Or rather, ._theming.scss is not adding the `background-color` property.

Kindly note that I have already imported `MatButtonModule` everywhere and it's working everywhere else in the project but in `mat-menu`s.

This is `dropdown.component.html`:

```
//this button is not the one I'm talking about, this is just the button which opens and closes 
the dropdown custom component and accepts an arrow, a title, and an icon

<button
    mat-button
    disableRipple
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-open': isOpen, 'no-arrow': !hasArrow }"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="theMenu"
    (menuOpened)="onMenuOpen($event)"
    (menuClosed)="onMenuClose($event)"
    #theMenuTrigger
  >
    <ng-container *ngIf="hasIcon">
      <mat-icon svgIcon="{{ icon }}">{{ icon }}</mat-icon>
    </ng-container>
    <div *ngIf="!!title">{{ title }}</div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="hasArrow"
      ><mat-icon
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-open': isOpen }"
        svgIcon="arrow-down"
        class="icon-arrow__down"
      ></mat-icon
    ></ng-container>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #theMenu="matMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-menu>
```

And this is my `navbar.component.html` where I'm using the dropdown component:

```
          <dropdown-menu title="حساب کاربری" icon="profile" [hasArrow]="true">
            <div class="container__welcome--user">
              <span
                mat-menu-item
                disabled
                class="navbar__personal-info-item text__welcome--user"
              >
                <mat-icon
                  svgIcon="profile"
                  aria-hidden="false"
                  aria-label="profile SVG icon"
                ></mat-icon>
                سلام، {{ personalInfo }}</span
              >
              <span
                mat-menu-item
                disabled
                class="navbar__personal-info-item email"
                *ngIf="!!traderEmail"
                >{{ traderEmail }}</span
              >
            </div>

            <a
              mat-menu-item
              routerLink="/user/settings"
              [queryParams]="{ tab: 'security' }"
            >
              <mat-icon
                class="icon__user--account"
                svgIcon="security-settings"
                aria-hidden="false"
                aria-label="settings SVG icon"
              ></mat-icon>
              <span>تنظیمات امنیتی</span>
            </a>
            <a
              mat-menu-item
              routerLink="/user/settings"
              [queryParams]="{ tab: 'kyc' }"
            >
              <mat-icon
                class="icon__user--account"
                svgIcon="kyc-settings"
                aria-hidden="false"
                aria-label="kyc SVG icon"
              ></mat-icon>
              <span>احراز هویت</span>
            </a>

            //THIS BUTTON IS THE ONE I'M TALKING ABOUT

            <button
              mat-flat-button
              color="accent"
              class="sign-out-button"
              (click)="requestSignOut()"
            >
              <span> خروج </span>
            </button>
          </dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: Can you tell me where and how you set `background-color` in your html? It is little hard to find. :-)

Comment: @Linker `color` attribute is supposed to add the `background-color` style. look for `color="accent" on my `button`.

Comment: I have added `ngStyle` sample code for you. Please check and let me know. :-)

Comment: can you create stackblitz for youe example to understand what's the problem there.In mat-menu button color is working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu-suf8x6?file=app/menu-icons-example.html

Answer (score 0):

To set color of button I suggest to use `style`.
If you set `style="color: red !important;"` inside the button. It will color the text

```
<button mat-flat-button style="color: red !important
(click)="select('Basic.Item1')">Basic.Item1
</button>
```

**OUTPUT will be like below** 

[image]

If you set style="background-color: red !important;" .  It will color the background of the text

```
<button mat-flat-button style="background-color: red !important
(click)="select('Basic.Item1')">Basic.Item1
</button>
```

OUTPUT will be like below 
[image]

You can also use `[ngStyle]="mystyle"` like 
**HTML**

```
<button mat-flat-button [ngStyle]="mystyle"
    (click)="select('Basic.Item1')">Basic.Item1
    </button>
```

**TS**

```
 mystyle:any= { backgroundColor: 'red'};
```

**Note:** `!important` will override the CSS of the button for specific attribute.

Comment: but I don't want to hardcode it. My question is, why isn't mat-button color attribute working in this specific dropdown component?

Comment: @NewshaNik ok then you can use `[ngStyle]` by using that you can bind your style dynamically from your `*.ts` file. If you want that I can give you a sample code or you can check that link for `ngStyle` [Link for ngStyle](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/using-ngstyle-in-angular-for-dynamic-styling) :-)